# Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction

Tags: java, mysql, multithreading, insertion, executor

I am trying to insert using two different threads in mysql database. Insertion is being done by prepared statement. Inserting in a batch of 500.

//g1 is object made global to be accessed by classes implementing runnable

```
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

    Callable< Map<String, Set<String>>> callable2 = new PolyStrain();
    Callable<Map<String, Phenotype>> callable3 =  new DataPolymor();


    g1.kol=new HashMap<String, Set<String>>();

    g1.mapPheno = new HashMap<String, Phenotype>();


    Future<Map<String, Set<String>>> future = executor.submit(callable2); // hashmap of allele and strains
    Future<Map<String, Phenotype>> future1 = executor.submit(callable3); //hashmap of allele and chro,location

    g1.kol = future.get();
    System.out.println(g1.kol.size());


    g1.mapPheno= future1.get();

    System.out.println(g1.mapPheno.size());

    executor.shutdown();

    InsertStrain dp1 = new InsertStrain(); //data entry for allele and strain and frequency
    Thread t1= new Thread(dp1);
    t1.start();

    InsertPheno ip1 = new InsertPheno();
    Thread t2 = new Thread(ip1);
    t2.start();
```

The problem I am facing is, the thread two gets started, however, it doesn't work for insertion. Thread dp1 completes its task.
After completion of dp1 following is thrown:

```
Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction
```

I have set the

```
mysql> SELECT @@GLOBAL.tx_isolation, @@tx_isolation, @@session.tx_isolation;
```

Also,

```
mysql> set innodb_lock_wait_timeout=100
```

I am wondering, even if the thread 2 starts, why it doesn't begin insertion?
Any help shall be highly appreciated.
Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm guessing the inserts from your first transaction is locking a number database object causing the second transaction to be postponed until the first transaction completes

Comment: @ gerrytan - 
Oh, but that shouldn't be the case, correct?
How can I overcome this hurdle?

Comment: None of us would know the answer to that since it depends on your business requirement. Maybe you should explain to us why you wanted to do inserts in multiple thread in the first place?

Comment: insertion one table has primary key which acts as foreign key in other table's insertion. 
Can that be the reason for this?

Comment: @  gerrytan 
to speed up the insertion and learn mutli threading :)

Comment: @DeathMetal What you did is like by the book example of transaction deadlocks! There are many possible answers to you question how to overcome it, for example: `Use only one transaction`

Comment: Hmm I'd say using multiple threads will only speed it up if the bottleneck was in java in the first place. If 10 people trying to rush through a door, it wouldn't make it any faster if the door can only fit 1 right?

Comment: @ Antoan Milkov: Can you please elaborate?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18854988/lock-wait-timeout-exceeded-try-restarting-transaction-using-jdbc this question solved my problem.